# using handlebars #each to send a massage "success" or "failed" but my code always is sending success messges even when it's wrong

Tags: javascript, express, mongoose, handlebars.js

im trying to send a message if the registration of a user is succeful or fairule but the 1 message is being always printed the "O cadastro foi bem sucedido" and never the other one

and when its a faiuere registration it should too being sent to other page, but its going to the wrong one

my java scrpit
'''

```
     const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router() // essa biblicoteca  padrão do express serve pra abrir uma rota de outro diretório como exemplo a pasta "routes/index"
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
require("../../models/Cadastro")
const CadastroUsuario = mongoose.model("usuario")
      router.post('/cadastrar/cadastrado', (req, res) => {
            res.render("user/cadastrar")
            /////////////////////validando o formulário com regras
            var erros = []
            if(!req.body.nome || typeof req.body.nome == undefined || req.body.nome == null){
                erros.push({texto: "nome inválido"})
            }
            if(req.body.nome.lenght < 3){
                erros.push({texto: "Nome muito pequeno"})
    
            }
    
            if(!req.body.email || typeof req.body.email == undefined || req.body.email == null){
                erros.push({texto: "email inválido"})
            }
    
            if(!req.body.senha || typeof req.body.senha == undefined || req.body.senha == null ){
                erros.push({texto: "senha inválida"})
            }
    
            if(req.body.senha.lenght <= 6){
                erros.push({texto: "Senha muito pequena"})
    
            }
            if(erros.length > 0){
                res.render("user/cadastrar", {erros: erros})
                ////////////////////////////
            }else{
                const novoUsuario = {
                    nome: req.body.nome,
                    email: req.body.email,
                    senha: req.body.senha
                }
                new CadastroUsuario(novoUsuario).save().then(() => {
                    req.flash("success_msg", "O cadastro foi bem sucedido")
                    console.redirect("/")
                }).catch((err) => {
                    req.flash("error_msg", "O cadastro foi mal sucedido")
                    res.redirect("/user/cadastrar")
                
                })
            }
        })
```

'''

html for success and error msg
'''

```
{{#if success_msg}}
  <p> {{success_msg }} </p>


{{/if}}

{{#if error_msg}}
    <p> {{error_msg}} </p>

{{/if}}
```

'''

html form
'''

```
    {{#each erros}}  <!-- pra cada ERRO -->
        {{texto}} <!-- printa o erro (da página user.js onde é cadastrado o usurario)-->

    {{else}}
    {{/each}}

<main>
    <form  action="/user/cadastrar/cadastrado" method="POST">
        <label for="nome" Nome:></label>
            <input type="nome" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="Digite Seu Nome">
      
        <label for="email" E-mail:></label>
            <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Digite Seu E-mail">
        <label for="senha"Senha:></label>
            <input type="password" id="senha" name="senha" placeholder="Digite Sua Senha">
        <button type="submit"> Cadastrar</button>
    </form>

</main>
```

'''

my main aplication java scripit
'''

```
const express = require('express')
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const router = require('./routes/admin')
const app = express()

const session = require("express-session")
const flash = require("connect-flash")
//biblioteca de arquivos estáticos de diretórios
const path = require("path")


//rota a pasta routes
const admin = require("./routes/admin")
const index_user = require("./routes/index/user")
const index_index = require("./routes/index/index")



//configurações das biblioteca

    //session---- uma seção é  um arquivo q o servidor guarda quando tem conexão com o usuario
    app.use(session({
        secret: "jamelaumn", //secret é uma chave pra quando é gerado uma sessão
        resave: true,
        saveUninitialized:true
    }))
//flash
    app.use(flash()) // flash é um tipo de sessão que só aparece uma vez na página, assim que é recarregado ela some


// precisa configurar o middleware pra trabalhar com sessões (sessions)
//middleware --- middlware o que fica no meio da conexão do servidor pro usuário
    app.use((req, res, next) => {
        res.locals.success_msg = req.flash("success_msg") //locals cria uma variável global (pode acessar em qualquer parte da aplicação)
        res.locals.error_msg = req.flash("error_msg")
        next()
    })

    
//bodyparser
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
    app.use(bodyParser.json())
    
// handlebars
    const hbs = handlebars.create({defaultLayout: 'main'});
    app.engine('handlebars', hbs.engine)
    app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')
// mongoose

    mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/formulario").then(() => {
        console.log("banco de dados conectado com sucesso")
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("deu um erro"+err)})
    

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////q
   /*
    const novoUsuario =  mongoose.model('usuario')
    new novoUsuario({
        nome: "kaynan",
        email: "oi.@gmail.com",
        senha: "123"
    }).save().then(() => {
        console.log("usuario cadastrado")
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("erro ao cadastrar usurio"+err)
    })*/
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////q
// static ---- public
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")))

//pasta de arquivos estáticos (como bootsrap)

    


    
   //rota padrão
   /*
   app.get('/', (req, res) => {
       res.render('oi')
   })
    //rota da pastar routes
    router.get('/admin', (req, res) => {

        res.send("admin pagina")
    })
      
*/
    app.use('/admin', admin)
    app.use('/user/', index_user)
    app.use('/', index_index)
   const PORTA = 9627
   app.listen(PORTA, () => {console.log("servidor rodando")})
```

'''
[THE PHOTO OF WHERE I THINK IS THE MAIN PROBLEM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iUHH.png)

Comment: What is `console.redirect("/")`?

Comment: I think there is a mix of problems here, making it difficult to identify a problem because it is likely a few different problems compounding one another. Some obvious issues: the `res.render("user/cadastrar")` in the POST handle for `'/cadastrar/cadastrado'` should be removed as it is handled further down in the handler function. And `console.redirect("/")` should be `res.redirect("/")`.